# Overpass API: Find road intersection points with defined line

Tags: overpass-api

I have a geometrical line and I would like to have all intersection points where this line passes roads.

So far I have a line, defined by coordinates. I am looking for all intersection points with roads:

```
way(40.73792521975707,-74.00163173675537,40.743062717636114,-73.98819923400879);
   (way["highway"~"primary|secondary|tertiary|trunk|service|residential"];
    node(w););
out meta;
```

As an output I expect a series of points where this line crosses roads and such.

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/BZB

Comment: the *Overpass API* does not provide functions for e.g. *geometric* intersections; the *Overpass QL* Intersection function will return all *nodes* that are common in both input sets. consider QGIS instead, as it provides user friendly access to OSM data for your AOI and the necessary functions.

Comment: you will need to load the osm data into postgis and use the ST_Intersection https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following examples from [Overpass API by Example](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#Search_for_street_intersections) as a starting point to easily achieve what you're looking for.

**Find intersections of major and minor roads:**

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way[highway~"^(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary)_link)$"]->.major;
way[highway~"^(unclassified|residential|living_street|service)$"]->.minor;
node(w.major)(w.minor);
out;
```

Please adjust major/minor according to your requirements.

To find intersections without a common node, you can use `way(around:0)`. The [documentation on "around"](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Relative_to_other_elements_.28around.29) explicitly mentions "*A radius of 0 can be used for a way intersection test on outer/inner points.*".

There are also multiple examples in this guide, such as ["n adjacent ways"](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#.C2.AB_n_.C2.BB_adjacent_ways), which returns such ways. To get the exact lat/lon locations for the intersection point (e.g. no OSM node exists in the data), you indeed need some post processing.

Comment: you are exactly right; `way[highway](around:0,40.73792521975707,-74.00163173675537,40.743062717636114,-73.98819923400879);(._;>;);out geom;`

Comment: I expected the post-processing, but no problemo