# Finding all roads entering or leaving a jurisdiction

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to find all the roads that leave a province. After messing around with a few different options I decided to try and do this with the Overpass API for OpenStreetMap. I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296278/overpass-api-find-road-intersection-points-with-defined-line) question and answer that seemed reasonable for accomplishing this and that lead me to implementing this:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way[highway~"^(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|unclassified|residential|living_street|service|(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary)_link)$"]->.road;
way[admin_level="4"]->.border;
way(around.road:0)->.aroundroad;
node(w.border)(w.aroundroad);
out;
```

This works reasonable well, but I'm having an issue where I get intersections that are as a result of a road not crossing the border, simply meeting it. For example, the lower intersection in this image:

[image: road and borders intersecting]

I've flailed around trying to figure out how to filter these out but I'm fairly new to GIS in general and OpenStreetMap specifically. Is there a way to deal with this? or should I attempt an entirely different solution?