# Intersection of major and minor roads from OSM using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, overpass-api

I found this question -> [Overpass API: Find road intersection points with defined line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296278/overpass-api-find-road-intersection-points-with-defined-line) that has an answer with a solution using `overpass API`:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way[highway~"^(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary)_link)$"]->.major;
way[highway~"^(unclassified|residential|living_street|service)$"]->.minor;
node(w.major)(w.minor);
out;
```

Is there a way to translate this query into PostgreSQL? I already have an OSM pbf imported using `osmosis` into a PostGIS database.

Comment: try osm2pgsql to import OSM data into PostGIS